# Visual studio ORM designer option

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2010

linq to sql visual studio Object-Relational designer generates C# entity class names same as the table names (except pluralizing it).

so if the table name is **authors** it generates entity class with name **"author"**. If the table name is **Customers** it generates class with name **"Customer**". Is there any option that can be set to 
make the designer generate entity class names as pascal cased.

I am using VS 2010 if that makes any difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class names easily in the designer, they do not have to match the table names at all. It could not easily use Pascal case automatically, how would it know what to capitalise?

Comment: Hmmm...isn't that a lot of work if all the class names and their properties need to be changed. I was thinking if there was an option that could be set. If the schema changes, the table needs to be refreshed and i guess this might again revert back the changes made.